# IO error when executing runhaskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to execute a main method within one of my classes in haskell.  When I run the command `runhaskell mod12PA.hs` I get an error and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
-- The main program: read points from stdin, write an SVG file to stdout. 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter points: "
  points <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Points: " ++ points)
```

The error:

```
<interactive>:41:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: runhaskell :: t0 -> b0 -> c

<interactive>:41:12: error: Variable not in scope: mod12PA

<interactive>:41:20: error: Variable not in scope: hs :: a -> b0
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure out that I needed to be compiling the file outside of ghci and then running the executable. I was trying to execute the file from within ghci  which was not working.

Ran ghc --make mod12PA.hs

Then mod12PA.exe

Answer (score 0):

While you do need to run the command outside of GHCi, `runhaskell mod12PA.hs` should work. (`runhaskell` serves a different purpose than `ghc --make`: it runs the code without compiling it.)